# How to Trigger a build pipeline depends on create PR request source branch in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request, azure-repos

I have a Develop branch and Master. My task is to trigger the build pipeline when I create a Pull Request from Develop to Master before merge, depends on Develop branch. The trigger should be from source branch. Can we add tags to trigger the build pipeline based on source branch. I am using classic pipelines and new to ADO. how can I achieve this. Please someone help me to achieve this in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a pipeline to trigger when a PR is opened but before it is merged you would need to add a branch policy on master branch to have a build validation step. This will trigger the pipeline to run whenever a PR is opened to master

[Build Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation)

Comment: But that wouldn't build the source branch. That would build the merge target between the source and destination branches.

Comment: @DavidCox88 Thanks for the answer, Its triggering the build pipeline. Can we achieve this just adding the label or tag on PR. Because it always trigger the build pipeline when I raise the PR with Main. Am using it for HotFix. Based on tag or label can we trigger build for particular branch.

Comment: @Harish334363 Because you are using classic UI your options are more limited compared to using yaml to define your pipelines. Triggering the pipeline this way using tags or labels is not possible with the classic UI. I would recommend switching to yaml which gives you create flexibility and customisation

Comment: @DavidCox88 Thank you for the reply. How can we achieve this with yaml. I will suggest my team if yaml works fine. Please help me with the steps. Thank you.

Comment: @Harish334363 Apologises I thought this was possible but having just checked the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pr?view=azure-pipelines) you can only use yaml PR triggers if using GitHub or BitBucket Cloud

Comment: @DavidCox88 Thanks for the reply. Its working fine for me, But just curious to know for sake of my knowledge how can we achieve this in GitHub and BitBucket by using YAML

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PR trigger behaviour varies, depending on which SCM you're using: Azure Repos Git, GitHub, or Bitbucket Cloud. With BB Cloud, the PR build will be triggered when the PR is opened or updated, but not when it is merged. The filter input can be used to specify branches for PR trigger.

Details for each SCM system can be found by clicking on the links on the "[Triggers in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops)" documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The way how to set that up does depend on your source-code version control software you are using. For GitHub you need to install the "Azure Pipeline" GitHub App.

[image]

Then configure a pipeline in AzureDev Ops and enable "Continous integration" in "Triggers" section.

P.S.: To avoid that the compile check of a PR will result in published artefacts you can either have to different pipelines or - that's what I try to achieve - one pipeline where the artefacts are just being generated when the PR is merged.

Comment: This might be an option I just found on VisualStudio Marketplace 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ivanboyko.release-master-build&targetId=14d93276-77d9-400f-a7db-875736f1621c